# How to extend size of mounted ext4 /home gpt partition without loss of data?

Tags: filesystems, ext4, gpt

I have GPT partitioning for my drive:

```
$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda
Disk /dev/sda: 465.8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 8E38B9BD-5EA6-40F6-9C2B-98E5F801B29D

Device         Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1       2048   1050623   1048576   512M EFI System
/dev/sda2    1050624  59643903  58593280    28G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda3   59643904  90894335  31250432  14.9G Linux swap
/dev/sda4   90894336 588941311 498046976 237.5G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda5  588941312 976771071 387829760   185G Linux filesystem

$ mount | grep /dev/sda
/dev/sda2 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered)
/dev/sda4 on /home type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)

$ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   512M  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0    28G  0 part /
├─sda3   8:3    0  14.9G  0 part [SWAP]
├─sda4   8:4    0 237.5G  0 part /home
└─sda5   8:5    0   185G  0 part 
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

The `sda5` partition was meant to be `/media/DATA` partition, but I changed my mind, and I am using the `/home` to store my data. But, the `/home` is almost full, now.

How can I grow (`+100GB`) mounted `/home` partition without loss of data?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used `fdisk` in a long time. I use `gdisk`, and with `gdisk` you can delete `/dev/sda5`, and then delete `/dev/sda4`, and then create sda4 again with same beginning offset (*be careful*) as before, but with size set to what you want it to be. Once that's done, save, and exit. You may be required to run `partprobe` (from `parted`) to refresh the `/proc/partitions`. Once `/proc/partitions` is refreshed with updated size of `/dev/sda4`, and `/dev/sda5` gone, then run `resize2fs /dev/sda4` to resize it. Also in `fdisk` before making any changes, make sure to set display units to sectors (using `u` command).

Comment: Do you know whether size changes (or `partprobe` updates in general) affect mounted partitions?

Comment: the best to affect in-use partitions is to run partx: after having done the gdisk voodoo, `partx -u /dev/sda4` would update it (perhaps partx -d /dev/sda5 would be needed no idea)., it can be checked by looking at the content of `/sys/class/block/sda4/size` before and after partx

Comment: @HaukeLaging --- IIRC, devices in use/mounted will not see these changes.

Comment: But then your proposal is not going to work, is it?

Comment: @HaukeLaging, I think with `partx -d ...`, and `partx -u ...` mentioned by @A.B, instead of `partprobe` the instructions will work